# CSS align being pushed to the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text box that I'd like to align to the right of the page next to an image but I can't figure out out to move from the bottom of the page (apologies very limited background at coding, so any help is greatly appreciated). Here is the CSS and the JS string variable, is there something off here?

```html
<table id="mtable" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="left"

<p><span style="font-size: 140%;"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #9db68c;"><strong style="font-size: 150%;"><span style="font-size: 150%;"><span style="font-size: 140%;">15</span><span style="font-size: 140%;">th Annual</span></span></strong></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #9db68c;"><strong style="font-size: 150%;"><span style="font-size: 140%;">James McNaughton Tribute</span></strong></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #9db68c;"><strong> </strong></span></p>
<strong>
<div id="_mcePaste" style="display: inline !important; font-size: 100%;"><span style="font-size: 120%;">Saturday January 25th, 2020</span></div>
</strong> <span style="color: #9db68c;"><strong>
<div id="_mcePaste">Live Music, Raffles, Giveaways,</div>
<div id="_mcePaste">     Drink Specials, Free Food &amp; Much More!</div>
<div id="_mcePaste">Mulcahy&rsquo;s Pub &amp; Music Hall</div>
<div id="_mcePaste">3232 Railroad Avenue</div>
<div id="_mcePaste">Wantagh, NY 11793</div>
<div id="_mcePaste">1:00pm - 9:00pm</div>
<div>$20 DONATION</div>

</strong></span><div>DOWNLOAD :&nbsp;<a href="/storage/2019 Flyer for Benefit_small.jpg">2020 EVENT FLYER</a></div></div>
The PTSD Veterans Association of Northport is dedicated to veterans from all eras who seek relief from their Post-Traumatic Stress. Please visit <a href="http://www.ptsdveteransassociation.org/">www.ptsdveteransassociation.org</a> to donate or for more information.</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Also note that #IDs shoudl eb unique *per page* ad should not be repeated. Also it might be appropriate to extract your *inline* css to a proper stylesheet.

Comment: *Here is the CSS and the JS string variable* there is no js in the snippet you provided.  Also your html seems invalid - besides the half opened table tag (which I assume is a copy and paste error), you have divs inside spans and strongs so perhaps you need to fix those first

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not organized. Use cleaner code. Something like below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <p>Column content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <p>Second column content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.